Graphic Issues Firewall gfuw in Ubuntu 22.04.4 on RPI4 8GB
I'm running ubuntu mate 22.04.4 LTS on my 8GB Raspberry Pi 4. After not using the device for some weeks I ran all updates and upgrades. I noticed that the VNC remote access was no longer working so I checked the firewall. All rules seem lost and I get a scrumbled graphic output below the "HOME" area in the GUI of the firewall.
I verified that the system is up to date. I also removed the firewall and GUI and reinstalled it.
I'd be very happy to hear advice or experience on that issue.

